# How to react on salt-master to minion being unreachable

Tags: salt-stack

I'm quite new to salt. The following is what I try to archive:
Let's say I have a salt-master, minion1, minion2 . If minion1 becomes unreachable for the salt-master a service should be started on minion2.

As far as I understand normally I would configure a beacon on minion1 and a reactor on the salt-master. However, since the event is "minion1 loosing connection" a beacon on minion1 can't fire an event.

Comment: Obviously a minion cannot send an event if it cannot reach master so the only way to do this is check from the master.
You can setup a cronjob to check for minion1 availability and if you cannot reach then start the service on minion2.

Comment: @atsa Thank you for your comment thats what I ended doing. However, it feels a bit wrong. Not really using salt to monitor the minion instead use cron + a small shell script.

Comment: you can also use the salt scheduled task if you don't like cron. I say obviously because in case of a network issue there is no way the minion can connect to the master and tell it its down. also it would be a waste of resources to check all minions if they are connected(think of 10k minions)

Comment: Maybe you can react on failure of minion1 by sending an event from minion2 every x seconds and check if minion1 is down. if its down do something on minion2. This would require your state to understand that minion1 failed and run something on minion2 after that failure.
But if minion2 becomes unreachable you would have an issue. This might get complicated though. Maybe you can have some more high level info on what you want to do to see if some other solution can be taken.

Comment: @atsa thank you for your time and thoughts I will look into salts scheduled task and otherwise let be as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved a similar problem. I have a database cluster(db1, db2, db3), and I want my application to failover to a different database if one fails.
Here is how I implemented it:

Add dynamic pillar to provide a list of available db servers:

```
{% set db_hosts = [] %}
{%- for host in ['db1', 'db2', 'db3'] %}
{%- if salt.network.connect(host, 3306, timeout=2)['result'] == true %}
{%- do db_hosts.append(host) %}
{%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
{%- if db_hosts != [] %}
available_db_hosts:
  {{ db_hosts | yaml }}
{% endif %}
```

Use `{{ pillar.get('available_db_hosts')[0] }}` pillar in `myapp` state so that it always connects to the first available db host.

Add salt beacon to the database nodes in pillar:

```
beacons:
  service:
    - services:
        mysql-server:
          uncleanshutdown: /var/mysql-data/hostname.pid
    - interval: 10
```

Add a salt reactor:

```
{% if data['service_name'] == 'mysql-server' and data[data['service_name']]['running'] == false %}
failover_myapp:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: 'minion1'
    - args:
        mods: myapp
{% endif %}
```